# Netbeans appearance on linux

Tags: linux, netbeans

any ideas why such a drastic difference in appearance?  Have tried with Ubuntu 11.04 and 12.04 and various versions of netbeans with same results.
Images

[Netbeans when started normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxVpN.png)
and
[Netbeans when started as root or su user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU4XC.png)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, NetBeans stores its config by default in `${HOME}/.netbeans/*/etc/netbeans.conf` (for more details, see the [Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf#How_do_I_make_my_custom_startup_parameters_permanent.3F)). That's the first responsible between differences in NetBeans setup, as it is user dependent.

The option you should be looking at is `netbeans_default_options`, and you can change your l&f (look and feel) by adding (or changing if it's already set) `--laf`. Take a look at the [list of available l&f](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#available).

Notice that the default l&f is `javax.swing.plaf.metal`. (By the way, this looks like your config, as for your *'Netbeans when started normally'* screenshot.)

I have an issue in linux with menus in this look and feel, as they don't render appropriate borders and they don't stand out appropriately (see screenshot below). That's the reason I always use the more recent `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel`.

Your *'Netbeans when started as root or su user'* screenshot looks like the `SystemLookAndFeel` (from your image, I would say `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel`, though I'd have expected `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel`). In this case, the `SystemLookAndFeel` is determined at runtime, so you have to also take into account which java version your user is using. Different java versions use different l&f.

---

Screenshot: Menus in Netbeans 7.1.2 with Metal l&f in linux do not have appropriate borders.

[image: menu in Netbeans 7.1.2 with Metal l&f]

Comment: Thanks Alberto.  When i start netbeans with command line options --laf Nimbus or Metal, it is fine.                                                      However this is the issue that I am having..  I login to my linux system as **user** and i start netbeans, it doenst display properly.  I do `sux - user` and then run netbeans, it works fine.  Its the same user, only difference is I have run su..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you: You can start netbeans from the command line adding the `--laf` and it works. Fine. But... _I login into my linux system as user and I start NetBeans_--from the command line, or from the GUI?-- and _I do sux - user_--what is `sux`? If it is a typo and you mean `su -`, then all points to your shell config, but no linux expert here: I don't know how _your_ terminal loads your profile, neither how it could be different from the profile loaded by `su -` (from the man page: "Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly")

Comment: yes sux is similar to su but allows graphics programs to be started as well.  As ladar has pointed out below, it seems to be a netbeans bug.

Comment: @moh Thanks for the update. I would have missed it. I didn't notice you meant the text font (I though you changed it intentionally in NetBeans preferences).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you may change the look of applications by placing configuration files in your home directory. In this case the normal user and the root user will have different files in their home directories. You may check this by entering "ls -al" as normal and as root user and by comparing both listings.

Comment: Hi, I am running the netbeans as **nbuser** and getting this issue.  If I run `sux -` to **nbuser** (from nbuser) and then run netbeans, then it displays properly..  So its definitely not the configuration files thats in the home directory..

Answer (score 0):

As for the normal user screenshot, there is a bug in Ubuntu 12.04, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/125609/netbeans-all-menu-fonts-are-bold-after-upgrade-to-12-04

Or more precisely https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/669159

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855597/413020), it is an Ubuntu bug. You have a nice workaround here:

[Netbeans and Ubuntu Unity](http://blogs.kiyut.com/tonny/2012/06/11/netbeans-and-ubuntu-unity/#.T9dexbnz7RY)

Briefly, try installing the [Java Ayatana plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/41822/java-ayatana)

(I don't have Ubuntu, so I haven't tested it myself.)